# Connecting SQL Azure with Android

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connecting SQL Azure from my android application. The code is working fine for Java application where I managed to fetch data from SQL Azure but it throws error for my android. Below is my code and error message.
Code:

```
String connectionString =
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://serversql.database.windows.net:1433" + ";" +  
                "database=dbname    " + ";" + 
                "user=user@serversql" + ";" +  
                "password=password";
            Connection connection = null;  // For making the connection
            Statement statement = null;    // For the SQL statement 
            ResultSet resultSet = null;    // For the result set, if applicable 
        try
        {

            // Ensure the SQL Server driver class is available.
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");              
            // Establish the connection.
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            String filename = "SVPoster.jpg";
            String sql = "Select * from VoucherTable";
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            int count;
            if(resultSet.next())
            {
                Blob test = resultSet.getBlob("Voucher"); 
                InputStream x=test.getBinaryStream();
                int size=x.available();
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"
                        + filename);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = x.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                x.close();
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Error Message

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host server.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Comment: As a side note, if this is going to be an android application for mass distribution, you really should not put the connection to the SQL Azure database (or any datastore) into the application itself. This puts the keys to that kingdom into the hands of anyone that has the appliation. You should instead use a data service, perferrably hosted close to the data, to handle any data requests. Not only does this protect the database from uncontrolled, unmonitoried access, but gives you the ability to implement features like data caching that will help you scale up as demand on the service increased.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey thanks for the info.. I read an article after I post the question where they suggest to use WEB SERVICE...

Comment: That's precisely what I'd do chinna. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because of the SQL Azure firewall.  You will probably have to open up that for it to be used:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx

Since you don't know the IP addresses of Android apps, I would think the choices are:

- Open the firewall up completely (start at 0.0.0.0 end at 255.255.255.255)
- Create a WCF service that you can call from Android and give that access to the database, this is probably a better solution as it is also more secure.

Comment: Once i change the firewall i got new error..... com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed". ClientConnectionId:ec331467-d01a-46d8-a3f2-db63aefe255f

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is correct this will allow any device to connect to your database, for your error of socket closed put this at the end of your connectionurl and test it out ;ssl=request.

Maybe this can workout.