# Connecting to SQL Azure with Android

Tags: android, azure-sql-database

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to connect to a SQL Azure database to extract data from a table.  I've searching all over for a good example, but unable to find one.  I've found this article [Connecting SQL Azure with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799567/connecting-sql-azure-with-android) and try, but it crashed my when it try to connect.

We have couple tables in SQL Azure with about 500 records in each table.  I need to connect to it from an Android device and extract the data into the local database (SQLite).  Does anyone have a good example of how to connect to SQL Azure to extract data?  I've tried to use JDBC written under ASYNCTASK function, but it does not work.  It crashed when it try to make the connection.

Can you give me some suggestion what is the best method: JDBC, Azure Mobile Services or something else.  If you have example, I would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

Typically connecting directly is not a good idea. Have you considered implementing an API to sync via. The sync framework might help as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sync

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you check out [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-android/)

that way, you're not necessarily opening up your Azure SQL and connecting to it directly.